# How to get user id in mongodb and use it in jwt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

```
collection.insertOne({username: username, password: password}).then((err, user) => {
    const payload = user._id
    jwt.sign(payload, 'aspect', (err, token) => {
        console.log(token)
    })
})
```

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(err)`?

Comment: remove the `err` from the then promise and use `.catch(err)`

Answer (score 0):

`InsertOne` has 3 possible signatures:

```
insertOne(docs: Object, callback: MongoCallback<InsertOneWriteOpResult>): void;
insertOne(docs: Object, options?: CollectionInsertOneOptions): Promise<InsertOneWriteOpResult>;
insertOne(docs: Object, options: CollectionInsertOneOptions, callback: MongoCallback<InsertOneWriteOpResult>): void;
```

You're are using the Promise signature as you're not providing a callback function.

So the return value is `InsertOneWriteOpResult`, how does that look like?

```
{
    insertedCount: number;
    ops: Array<any>;
    insertedId: ObjectID;
    connection: any;
    result: { ok: number; n: number };
}
```

Meaning you need to change your code to firstly only have 1 input for the promise resolution, and second use `insertedId` and not `_id`, like so:

```
collection.insertOne({username: username, password: password}).then((userInsertResult) => {
    const payload = userInsertResult.insertedId
    jwt.sign(payload, 'aspect', (err, token) => {
        console.log(token)
    })
})
```